Crop raster with shapefile that has different projections
I tried to terra::crop() a SpatRaster (e.g. from the ForestClim database downloaded from here [6GB download]) with a shapefile, to keep only data for Belgium:
# shapefile
ISO <- countrycode("Belgium", origin = 'country.name', destination = 'iso3c')
shp <- gadm(country=ISO, level=0, 
            path = tempdir(), 
            version="latest")
crs(shp) <- "epsg:4326"

# raster
r <- rast(~/Downloads/ForestClim_01.tif) # download link above
crs(r) <- "epsg:4326"

# crop
cr <- crop(r, shp, mask=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)
Error: [crop] extents do not overlap

I have tried to understand this error but without success. I don't understand why this doesn't work as it worked perfectly with my CHELSA data.

You might put [6GB download] above for the unwary.

crs(shp) <- "epsg:4326" does not change the projection of your data, this is just an assignment or definition respectively. To change projections (e.g. to match datasets and make extents overlap), you need to use terra::project().

As noted in the previous answer, both files have difference CRS. In these cases, it is often easier to project an sf/SpatVector object to match the target raster rather than the other way around. I have included some code to help you identify the CRS for your r object. The CRS is a PROJ4 string, which R is moving away from in favour of EPSG codes. Fortunately, there are online resources such as https://epsg.io/ where you can search for equivalent codes (in this case, EPSG:3035). If you need the output in WGS84/EPSG:4326, comment below and I will update my answer.
library(countrycode)
library(geodata)
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)

# Shapefile converted to sf object (no need to assign CRS as it already has one)
ISO <- countrycode("Belgium", origin = 'country.name', destination = 'iso3c')
shp <- gadm(country=ISO, level=0, 
            path = tempdir(), 
            version="latest") %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Raster
r <- rast("ForestClim_01.tif")

# Return CRS of r
crs(r, proj = TRUE)
# [1] "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"

# Project shp to match CRS of ForestClim_01.tif using EPSG code found @ https://epsg.io/
shp3035 <- st_transform(shp, 3035)

# First try crop and mask combined
cr <- crop(r, shp3035, mask = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)

# If crop and mask combined does not work, then run them separately
cr <- crop(r, shp3035, overwrite = TRUE)
cr <- mask(cr, shp3035, overwrite = TRUE)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data = cr) +
  geom_sf(data = shp3035, fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = "transparent")



Thank you for your help, looks to be the better solution, I just has a problem with mask in cropfunction, but it works when I separate mask from crop.

The EPSG for ForestClim is epsg:3035. Therefore, you need to project it to epsg:4326 first before cropping.
# raster
r <- rast(~/Downloads/ForestClim_01.tif) # download link above
r <- terra::project(r, shp)


That sounds like a solution but it takes a long time.

You declare the CRS of your data to be "epsg:4326" --- but that is not correct. The coordinate reference system of the data does not change by declaring it to be something else.
I believe the simplest solution would be:
shp <- geodata::gadm(country="Belgium", level=0, path = tempdir())
r <- rast(~/Downloads/ForestClim_01.tif)
crp <- crop(r, project(shp, r))

